# pass a column name to a function using dplyr mutate without using the depreciated mutate_

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I realize this seems close to other questions already asked and it seems answered on https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html
but what I show below seems to follow that advise but without success.
Here is the data:

```
 d<-tibble(y=c(1,2,3,NA))
```

First something that works:

```
my.f <- function(df,column_var){
  df %>%
  mutate(z = y) %>%
  filter(!is.na(z))
}
my.f(d,quo(z))
```

Now something that I want to produce the same result, but doesn't work:

```
my.f <- function(df,column_var){
  df %>%
  mutate(!!column_var = y) %>%
  filter(!is.na(!!column_var))
}
my.f(d,quo(z))

Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  df %>%
mutate(!!column_var ="
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For setting variable names you'll need a string on the left hand side and `:=` instead of `=` in `mutate`.

You can use `quo_name` for turning `z` into a string for the column name.

Your function could then look like:

```
my.f = function(df, column_var) {
     column_var = enquo(column_var)

     df %>%
       mutate(!!quo_name(column_var) := y) %>%
       filter( !is.na(!!column_var) )
}

my.f(d, z)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
      y     z
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     2     2
3     3     3
```